# rsync writes to mounted NFS shares

Tags: rsync

QQ - I have remote directories that became unavailable last weekend but my servers were unaware of it so it was still "mounted" despite the fact that it was unreachable.

If I try to rsync data to an NFS mount is "mounted" but cannot be reached and am using the "remove source files" option what will happen?  Will the data be removed despite the fact that it couldn't be written or will the entire operation fail and the source file never be touched?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The entire operation will fail.

If in doubt, create a test file and attempt to copy it (just it) to the remote filesystem

```
ps -ef > /tmp/sacrifice
rsync -iavP --remove-source-files /tmp/sacrifice /path/to/NFS/filesystem/
ls -l /tmp/sacrifice
```